# How i ca fix this error (A RenderFlex overflowed by 104 pixels on the bottom.)

Tags: flutter, widget, trailing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TkAa.png)

> This (Trailing inside ListTile)
>   In Flutter

```
trailing: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), onPressed: (){}),

              Text("Hello"),
              new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down), onPressed: (){}),


            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 trailing: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                  child: new IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), onPressed: (){}),
            ),

            Expanded(child: Text("Hello")),
            Expanded(child: new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down), onPressed: (){})),


          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks for the simple answer

Answer (score -1):

```
    trailing: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up, size: 50.0,), onPressed: (){}),
          new Text("${cart_prod_qty}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),),
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, size: 50.0,) , onPressed: (){}),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```